# Owl Carousel 2 sync demo with item center

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

For example "demo-codepen", there are 4 thumbnails, I want it only 3 (item: 3) and active (background blue) always in the center, how do?

For example "demo-jsfiddle", the first and last item is being wrong. Please help me. Thank you.

```
enter view demo
```

[demo-codepen](https://codepen.io/washaweb/pen/KVRxRW)
[demo-jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frez1nLd/9/)

How to make all can be loop together sync smoothly?

Comment: Can I using owlcarousel 2.x??

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your code using:

- Add custom navigation button
- Change position of these sliders same position

Custom navigation Code.

```
$(".owl-next").click(function(){
     if(owl1.currentItem + owl1.visibleItems.length < owl1.owlItems.length){
            itemClicked = 1;
        sync1.trigger('owl.next');        
     } else if(owl1.currentItem + itemClicked <= owl1.owlItems.length){
                var next = owl1.currentItem + itemClicked;
          console.log(next);
                sync2.find(".owl-item")
          .removeClass("synced")
          .eq(next)
          .addClass("synced");
          itemClicked += 1;          
                sync2.trigger("owl.goTo",next);
     }else{
            itemClicked = 1;
            sync1.trigger('owl.next');
     }
 });
  $(".owl-prev").click(function(){

     if(owl1.currentItem - owl1.visibleItems.length > 0){
        itemClicked = 1;
            sync1.trigger('owl.prev');
     }else if(owl1.currentItem + itemClicked <= 0){
            var prev = owl1.currentItem - itemClicked;
                sync2.find(".owl-item")
          .removeClass("synced")
          .eq(prev)
          .addClass("synced");
          itemClicked += 1;          
                sync2.trigger("owl.goTo",prev);
     }else{
       sync1.trigger('owl.prev');
     }
 });
```

Code here: [Code Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/owcfjaht/)

Comment: IF I use new owl-carousel in my project this won't help

Comment: Could you please send me console log error?? I think that some variable changed its name.

Comment: Here please.I only change new version of owl-carousel and get error of __Cannot read property 'owl' of undefined__ here my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Cheapskate/yfk0cL9w/1/ .

Comment: If you use newest version you can use: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

Comment: i don't have much free time to read API or read core owl. I'll comback later.

Comment: @HoangHieu, I am trying someting like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59436125/not-able-to-use-more-than-two-owl-carousel-2-thumbnails-on-the-page   can you help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

For your demo-codepen. For thumbnails to be three, set `var slidesPerPage = 3` in your JS code and for active item to be in the center, set `center: true` in sync2 carousel

For demo-jsfiddle, you can use the newer version of owl carousel. Currently, you are using 1.3.3 which does not have infinite loop. You can use the latest version that has this feature and it will make sure the first and last item remain in sync

Comment: For my demo-codepen, i added center: true and  set var slidesPerPage = 3, it's still don't working.

Comment: I have forked your codepen. Take a look at https://codepen.io/cdoshi/pen/dJNyaM. There are three thumbnails and active item is at the center